# How to make an element animate when dragged? Sliding menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My idea is I have a "carousel" of 3 elements, controlled by arrow keys. When I go left/right with the arrows, my 3 elements (which are text blocks) will move left or right, and **be clipped by a box** so they don't go off the screen but rather are masked like this:

Before scroll -
[image]

after scroll-
[image]

To do this I have set up my arrow keys to increment a number controlling which li element is on at a time:

```
  if(event.key == "ArrowRight")
    {
      if(this.midMenuIndex < 2)
      {
        this.midMenuIndex++;
      }
    } else if (event.key == "ArrowLeft")
    {
      if(this.midMenuIndex > 0)
      {
        this.midMenuIndex--;
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```html
<ul class = "menuText">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in augue sed nibh mollis sodales at in velit. Maecenas ullamcorper mollis posuere.
    </li>
    <li> 3rd </li>
</ul>
```

And for clipping I've tried: `clip-path: inset(10px 20px 30px 40px);`

Which does work, but it seems like if I move one li, text gets all squished and doesn't seamlessly get masked. For easing I wanted to use https://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/ to move the li elements, but am unsure as to the most efficient way to accomplish this scrolling in coordination with the incrementing number.

Is clip path the right way to go or another method?

Comment: Just in case...beware the [common UX problems associated with carousels](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/), if you don't already know them.